# Inject EntityManager in a service from another service

Tags: php, symfony, private

I'm extracting code from Controller to a kind of ApplicationService in a Symfony 3.4 App.

I've a concrete class for scraping data and another concrete transformer to change some data.

```
src\App\Service 

class CompanyScraping implements ScrapingInterface
{
    private $crawler;

    public function __construct(CrawlerInterface $crawler)
    {
        $this->crawler = $crawler;

    }

    public function extract()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function transform()
    {
        $transformer = new concreteTransformer();

    }
}

class concreteTransformer
{
    private $em;

    public __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

How could I pass the EntityManager to the concreteTransformer class if the EntityManager is not called in CompanyScraping class? I can't instantiating concreteTransformer with a new.

I'm thinking in this two options:

- Pass EntityManager to CompanyScraping, but I thik that is a wrong idea because CompanyScraping doesn't need this dependency.
- Extract transform method into a another class and pass the em from controller/console

```
$crawler =  new CompanyScraping(new GoutteClient());
$rawData = $crawler->extract(...);
$data = new concreteTransformer($em, $rawData);
```

Any other idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just inject the ConcreteTransformer into the CompanyScraping class?

Answer (score 0):

The first solution I thought of is to inject (not the EM, but) the Transformer into the Scraper class, as posted in the comments.

Such solution would, however, not address the underlying problem: is the Scraper scraping, transforming or both? In the latter case, it's not adhering to the single responsibility principle, because it has the responsibility for both scraping *and* transforming.

A design pattern that could be pretty effective to tackle this, is the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).
The idea in this case is to "decorate" the scraped results with a transformation.

The result would look somewhat like this:

```
class Transformer implements ScrapingInterface
{
    private $scraper;
    private $em;

    public __construct(ScrapingInterface $scraper, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->scraper = $scraper;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function extract()
    {
        return $this->transform($this->scraper->extract());
    }

    private function transform() {...}
}
```

It can be constructed as:

```
$crawler = new Transformer(new CompanyScraping(new GoutteClient()), $em);
```

In case you have multiple transformer implementations, you can make the decorator more generic:

```
class TransformingScraper implements Scraper
{
    private $scraper;
    private $transformer;

    public __construct(Scraper $scraper, Transformer $transformer)
    {
        $this->scraper = $scraper;
        $this->transformer = $transformer;
    }

    public function extract()
    {
        return $this->transformer->transform($this->scraper->extract());
    }
}

$crawler = new TransformingScraper(
    new CompanyScraping(new GoutteClient()),
    new ConcreteTransformer($em)
);
```

Comment: You're right, the worst case you have commented is the correct... The scrapper class has two responsabilities :( I have implemented your decorator solution. Thank you very much!